# How do I pass multiple warning filters to python -W?

Tags: python, warnings

According to [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#describing-warning-filters), I can pass multiple warning filters:

> When listing multiple filters on a single line (as for PYTHONWARNINGS), the individual filters are separated by commas

But when I try that, Python complains that it ignores the invalid option.  Here, I'm trying to pass `always::::` and `error::RuntimeWarning::`:

```
$ python -W 'always::::,error::RuntimeWarning::' -c "print('hello, world')"
Invalid -W option ignored: too many fields (max 5): 'always::::,error::RuntimeWarning::'
```

It works if I run

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="always::::,error::RuntimeWarning::" python -c "print('hello, world')"
```

but what is the syntax to pass this as a commandline flag?

Comment: As the text you quote indicates, the comma-separated syntax relates to [`PYTHONWARNINGS`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS). When using [`-W`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w), I think you just need to pass multiple instances of the option.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following to your script

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: I know I can do that in the script.  The question is how to do it via the command line.